# Concurrent programming - Threads

Tags: multithreading

I am having two threads, where I need to implement a new method run_both which takes two functions as parameters, and calls each of them in a new thread.
The method must return a tuple with the result of the both functions.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        x = y + z;
    }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        y = 1;
        z = 2;
    }
};
```

Comment: Language? Your examples look like Java. Also, is this a homework question? It sounds like it might be homework.

Answer (score 0):

In Github you can find a library which does exactly what you want. The link is [here](https://github.com/tirimatangi/Lazy).
The first chapter in the description gives an example. More examples can be found [in example-1.cc](https://github.com/tirimatangi/Lazy/blob/main/examples/example-1.cc). Hope this helps!